# How to backup a running system?

Tags: linux, backup, dd

I have a running Linux system, and I'd like to have a full backup of it using `dd`, which, in my limited knowledge is the only tool every system has.

The distro doesn't matter mainly because I should apply this approach to several different servers with different flavours installed, and I cannot install new software on these servers.

What is the most generic and efficient way to complete such task?

Comment: I think using LVM snapshots and then backing them up might be an option, though they can (or used to be) buggy.

Comment: Yeah, I don't trust LVM snapshots atm. ZFS ftw! :D

Comment: For actual backing up, I generally recommend [FSArchiver](http://www.fsarchiver.org), the successor to [partimage](http://www.partimage.org).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not so much a solution as a few nuggets of advice which may be helpful to consider if using `tar`/`cpio`/`rsync` etc. First, it might be a good idea to backup from a bind mount of your source filesystem (`mount --bind source mntdir`). This will have a similar effect as the `--one-file-system` options to `rsync` and `tar` and `-xdev` with `find`. It has the advantages of working if these options are unavailable (perhaps due to an old version, although note that bind mounts were introduced in Linux 2.4) and allowing files underneath mount points to be backed up, which may be desirable in some cases.

Second, I would advise to use numeric uids and gids where possible (`--numeric-owner` for `tar`, `--numeric-ids` for `rsync` and `--numeric-uid-gid` for `cpio`). If you restore a backup without this and an owner/group no longer exists or the uid/gid is different (this may happen particularly if a live disc is used to restore the backup), you can have one set of uids/gids used when restoring which become invalid after `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` are restored.

Also, take a look at [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/). The methods that they use to do the bulk of the backup may not be of use to you, but when it runs has options to backup boot sectors/partition tables and supports both MBR and GPT, so there may be some scripts there which can be copied/adapted to your purposes.

As a final 2 cents, I would consider `rsync` to be the standard way to do this. It is surely the most efficient method when doing incremental backups, although not so much for a one off full backup. Sure, it is not ubiquitous, but I think it is a mistake not to include it in the server edition of a distro. It may well already be installed on all of your servers.

Comment: Yeah, I think `rsync` is the way to go.

Comment: He did say a running file system.  Clonezilla, tar and rsync won't accurately copy a live filesystem.  Or you could say it will capture it, but when you restore you won't get an exact copy of a moment in time as is needed for the OS to properly restore without possibility of crashes or other errors.  This is because linux is a multitaskiing OS with multiple threads changing files at the same time as the file system needs to remain quiescent for the image capture.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dd` can in my experience cause problems when restoring later on because it reads the data at a block level from the device while the filesystem might be updating blocks in a different order. This results in filesystem errors on the restored device. It also requires you to restore to a block device (or else loop-mount the image), so it is not so flexible for restoring.

There are always issues when backing up a running system that does not support snapshots at the OS level, but I have had less problems using `cpio` (and using `tar` would be the same). There may be files that are incomplete or not in sync with each other, but the underlying filesystem itself will not have errors.
Another alternative to `dd` is rsync if you have that. You make sort of a snapshot to a different drive/server. With `find` and `cpio` it is easy to generate a timestamp file and do a second run with files changed after the timestamp (this runs much quicker than the orginal and give less chance of files being out-of-sync with each other), the same can be done with rerunning `rsync`.Neither `cpio` nor `rsync` deal with the bootsector etc. you should take care of that separately. `dd` is good for that as it seldom changes while you run `dd`.

For a complete restorable setup I make a dump of the partitioning (`fdisk -l` or `parted -l`), a copy of the bootsector, a list of filesystem types per partition, and `cpio` generated `.tar` files of the contents of the partitions (all burned on a CD/DVD). Restoring then implies booting from a life CD, restoring the bootsector, partitioning the drive, formatting the partitions and restoring the partitions from tar. (You should be able to do that without the boot sector restore by installing grub after the restoring of the various `.tar` files)

Comment: This will not always make an accurate image of a working multi-tasking file system.